# how to redirect to the specific url through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have a website and i want that whenever someone types in the domain it should take it to the dedicated path that i chose for it like when someone types www.gdrfa.info it should take the user to www.gdrfa.info/portal/pls/portal/ and if someone changes the url like www.gdrfa.info/portal/pls or changes anything after.info then too it should automatically redirect to my desired url can anyone tell me how can i do it i searched on web but could not find out what i wanted.

I tried

```
Redirect 301 "/old-page.html" "http://www.new.com/new-page.html"
```

Comment: You need to add more information to the question... Sure, it is possible to redirect a client to some fixed URL. But: is that all? Is there only one single URL? Or do you have a fixed list? How do those different targets differ, actually?

Comment: actually i want my url to look like this www.gdrfa.info/portal/pls/filename how can i do this.

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. Why do you think that just repeating what you already wrote helps to answer the open questions?